# What is the scope of Excel add-in's and VBA references?

Tags: vba, excel, add-in

When I install an add-in (via the checkbox) what are the rules / mechanics governing how long that add-in stays installed?  It seems that it is installed on the application level, meaning that it applies to any workbook in the excel application, until you uncheck it yourself.  If this is correct, this means that as long as a user installs the add-in themselves, they should be fine; but they will have to install it that first time (which could be done programmatically).

Regarding VBA references, I imagine these do not need to be 'checked' every time-  meaning it is in the scope of the document.  But if this is true, why do people recommend using late binding methods when the software is ready to be distributed?  Is late binding really just to make it compatible with different versions, but not necessarily to make it so the DLL is 'checked' as a reference?  Under this assumption, as long as everyone uses the same version of Excel as the me, would it be safe to forego late binding all together, and just add the references manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add-ins are installed to the Application-level.  You can fine-tune how an Add-in may be exposed (or not) to various Workbook(s) using Ribbon XML if needed.

> as long as a user installs the add in themselves, they should be fine; but they will have to install it that first time

Yes, they'll have to install it.

> Regarding VBA references, I imagine these do not need to be 'checked' every time- meaning it is in the scope of the document.

Yes, version control. It also saves you the hassle of having to try and programmatically add references. This can be done by path (which requires knowing the OS, version, etc. ) or the GUID (I've never actually been able to do this successfully).  Both of these would then require error-trapping (what if the path doesn't exist or is otherwise inaccessible? etc.).  So just use late binding.

While developing using early binding is helpful because of the intellisense, from a user perspective, there is generally no observable difference in how they might perform although EB is arguably faster, the difference is usually negligible for most applications. Related, if while using EB you rely on the `New` keyword to instantiate objects, I believe that the `CreateObject` function which you would use with LB is actually faster. This is probably not noticeable, though.

> can I forego the late binding all together, and be safe by just adding the references manually?

I would simply do the development with EB, and then modify the code to late-bound objects before compiling the Add-in.

Comment: That sounds like a plan.  I have actually heard that LB is slower than EB though.  Here is the website http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245115.  ***Early binding is the preferred method. It is the best performer because your application binds directly to the address of the function being called and there is no extra overhead in doing a run-time lookup. In terms of overall execution speed, it is at least twice as fast as late binding.***

So if I had a function that returns an ADODB.recordset, would I just change the return type to 'object'?

Comment: Yes, you would do like `Dim ado as Object 'ADODB.Recordset` but it would be more complicated, you will need to specifically enumerate any of the constants used in that library reference, too, for example you would need to `Const adLockReadOnly as Long = 1`, etc., for any constants that your functions use.

Answer (score 3):

Using late binding is better because you can't guarantee that every system will have the same references available.  So you should only select references that you can guarantee will be on every machine and distribute the DLL files for the rest.

As far as scope, the public subs/functions/variables in your add-in will be available to anything in the application as long as it is installed and active.  The references in the add-in will be available only to the routines in the add-in.

Comment: Well assuming that everyone I give the program to will be running the same version of excel, does that mean I can just do early binding for everything?

And if i'm understanding this right, by using late binding it just does something along the lines of "search for an object named ADODB.connection among the list of available references"?  So that it doesn't have to be version specific?

Comment: No.  It depends on many other factors.  For example, in our organization, only 10% of users have the references available to do regular expressions in VBA and they all have the same version of everything.

Comment: What about adding references to the add-in itself?  Notable because to be able to programmatically use add-in functionality, you have to add it as a reference.  Is this going to be a problem? I would imagine not, because the add in should always show up assuming it's installed & open.

Comment: Adding the reference doesn't put the DLL(or OCX, etc.) into the add-in.  The reference still needs to be installed on the target machine.

Answer (score -1):

I've had a very difficult time implementing an Add-in in Excel.
I've got buttons on a worksheet which reference code in the Add-in, and I've also got code in the worksheet which references functions in the Add-in.  What was really throwing me off, was that I could inactivate the Add-in (options, add-ins, Manage, uncheck) and the code continued to access the add-in.  This was particularly frustrating during development and debug of the Add-In, because what I wanted to do, was to inactivate the Add-In (during development) and have my application worksheet reference the open Add-In .xlsm development file.  What took me a while to figure out, was that due to the code "References" in the application worksheet, it was still calling to the code in the .xlam file, not the .xlsm.

Once I figured this out, things when smoother, but now, each time I make a change and want to test, I need to close my application, Inactivate the Add-in, Close Excel, Save my .xlsm as .xlam in the default Excel Add-Ins directory (which BTW requires administrator rights), Open excel, Activate the Add-in.  [Close Excel], Open my workbook application.  A throughly exhausting process.  Perhaps I could skip the last [Close Excel] step if the add-in becomes active immediately when checked.

And then dealing with users on Win10 and Win7 really complicates things.  Different path to default Add-in folder.  Users have to change references path, etc.  Very ugly.  Very Microsoft.